# Show that if the norms ∥⋅∥1 and ∥⋅∥2 are equivalent, then if space (X,∥⋅∥1) is complete, then the space (X,∥⋅∥2) is not necessary complete.

Tags: functional-analysis, separable-spaces, equivalent-metrics

X is complete if Cauchy sequence converges to it's limit in X
∀ε>0 ∃N: ∀n>N∶ ∥xn-x∥1<ε
So let (X,∥⋅∥1) – separable and xn - Cauchy sequence in (X,∥⋅∥1) and xn→x
∀ε>0 ∃N: ∀n>N∶ ∥xn-x∥1<ε
We have equivalent norms, which means:
∃a,b: a*∥⋅∥2≤∥⋅∥1≤b*∥⋅∥2
a*∥xn-x∥2≤∥xn-x∥1≤ε
∥xn-x∥2≤ε/a
That means (X,∥⋅∥2) is complete, isn’t it?
How can I prove it is not necessary complete?

Comment: The statement in the title is incorrect. The two norms are equivalent if and only if they induce the same topology, and separability is a topological property.

Comment: If the you're asking for the true statement Daniel provided, then since the norms are equivalent any ball in one norm is contained in a ball in the other norm. Thus their topological bases are the same, hence generate the same topology, hence separability follows.

Comment: @Iwassuspendedfortalking got it, thank you!  Is completness of (X,∥⋅∥1) not  necessary means completness of  (X,∥⋅∥2)?

Comment: @NataliaS You should edit your question and then I can provide an answer, I don't understand your question now. Do you mean if completeness in one norm implies completeness in another if the norms are equivalent?

Comment: @Iwassuspendedfortalking yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: @NataliaS Edit the question correctly and I'll type up an answer.

Comment: @Iwassuspendedfortalking done, I edited.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a,b>0$ such that for all $x\in X$ it is $\|x\|_1\leq a\|x\|_2$ and $\|x\|_2\leq b\|x\|_1$. Suppose that $(X,\|\cdot\|_1)$ is complete. We will show that $(X,\|\cdot\|_2)$ is also complete.

If $(x_n)\subset X$ is a Cauchy sequence for $(X,\|\cdot\|_2)$, then for any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $n_0$ such that for all $m,n\geq n_0$ it is $\|x_n-x_m\|_2\leq\varepsilon$. So, if $\varepsilon>0$, consider $\varepsilon/a>0$ and find $n_0$ such that for all $n,m\geq n_0$ it is $\|x_n-x_m\|_2<\varepsilon/a$. Then for such $n,m$ it is $\|x_n-x_m\|_1<\varepsilon$, so $(x_n)$ is Cauchy for $(X,\|\cdot\|_1)$. This space is complete, so $x_n\to x$ with respect to $\|\cdot\|_1$. But then $0\leq\|x_n-x\|_2\leq b\|x_n-x\|_1\to0$, so $x_n\to x$ with respect to $\|\cdot\|_2$, so $(x_n)$ is convergent in $(X,\|\cdot\|_2)$ and we are done.

A comment: keeping things neat helps out!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $(X,\|\cdot\|_1)$ is complete. Let $(x_n)$ be a Cauchy sequence in $(X,\|\cdot\|_2)$. In order to prove that $(X,\|\cdot\|_2)$ is complete, you want to find an $x\in X$ such that $\|x_n-x\|_2\to 0$. To do so, consider the following:

- Prove that $(x_n)$ is also Cauchy in $\|\cdot\|_1$, by using that the norms are equivalent.
- Since $(X,\|\cdot\|_1)$ is complete, there exists an $x\in X$ such that $\|x_n-x\|_1\to 0$. This is our candidate limit.
- Prove that $\|x_n-x\|_2\to 0$ using that the norms are equivalent.